# If $f:\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0,1\}\to\mathbb{R}$ satisfies $f(x)+2f\left(\frac 1 x\right)+3f\left(\frac x {x-1}\right)=x$, then $8f(4)=?$

Tags: functions, contest-math, solution-verification, functional-equations

> Let $f: \Bbb{R}\setminus\{0,1\}\to \Bbb{R}$ be a function such that $$f(x)+2f\left(\frac 1 x\right)+3f\left(\frac x {x-1}\right)=x\text{ for all }x\neq 0,1\,.$$
> Then, $8f(4)=$ ?

**My Attempt.**

[image]

[image]

Is it correct?

Comment: Please use MathJax to typeset Math.

Comment: Can you please explain the method for these sort of functional equations, I didn't get any satisfactory explanation to this

Comment: What have you tried?  The usual thing would be to substitute relevant values in the hopes that you see the same, finite, set of values recurring.

Comment: yes, but substituted in terms of x,1/x, and different functions of x

Comment: I don't understand.  If you want to do it in functional form, fine.  You start with the three functions $x, \frac 1x, \frac x{x-1}$.  Now you can compose these in whatever combinations, so do that.  What new functions do you get?  You should see that you really don't get very many.

Comment: Yeah, it's a homework problem. Can you do it for me?

Comment: ya, I did @N.V.Scott

Comment: well done @jayanth chowdary

Comment: It is correct (extra characters for comment limit)